# Question about Magento speed and adding Varnish cache

Tags: magento2, nginx, varnish, hosting

I got a task to speed up Magento 2 site. Now im facing with a huge problem.
Site is hosted on shared hosting (quite good and reputable company). There is plenty of power but every shared hosting has his own limits.

1st option: Move site to VPS and add nginx with Varnish (at moment apache). But there is problem. ~20 mailboxes and they are years old, filled with important data. And if i host that mail server on new VPS there will be definitely some spam/deliverability problems + moving them to VPS. I think self-hosted mail is not an option.

2nd option??: Buy a VPS from same company and add Varnish with nginx as frontend cache? HTTPS is needed. Ping from VPS to shared hosting 1ms. Or is it possible even when i use shared hosting? Or is there any point to do that kind of setup?

3rd option: I can add Redis cache(512mb), its not added yet but hosting supports that and try to optimize site overall performance, compress pictures etc...

And all that is needed to do with minimum downtime as possible.

Comment: How many product ,category and customer exit at your system

Comment: 3rd option is good for my view.

Comment: Have you test your web speed? If yes, how much score did you get? And which file / code made your web slower?

Comment: As @AmitBera told, the third option is better

Comment: @AmitBera 7k customers. ~300 products and 45 categories.

Comment: first, try with the 3rd option.Redis cache size need to increase 2GB minimum suggestion.Also, have to flush redis every at day night

Comment: please post your google pagespeed or webpagetest.org report, otherwise you just wasting money and time optimizing you dont know what...btw - redis will not help ...

Comment: @MagenX, As per as your idea what will be  best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the 3rd option about Redis cache. Magento supports it out-of-the-box, therefore you can't skip it. Use this possibility to speed up the transfer of data and instructions.